# What's the difference between public and private venues?

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand what's the exact meaning of public and private venues. From what I understand, a public venue would allow anyone to go to an event, and a private one would require you to be on a list. Is that correct?

Comment: There isn't one single way to distinguish *public* and *private*; you'll need to explain the context. For example, a *public* venue can be defined as one owned by the government, so it would be possible to have a private event in a public venue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: a public venue would indeed be open to anyone, though it may have hours of operation which restrict when people can go. A private venue could have anything from a guest list you need to be on to armed guards who will shoot you if you don't present an ID card and sign form 18-B in triplicate. The terms of entry to a private place are basically whatever the person who owns it wants them to be.